# Different users in iOS app with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am developing an app with different types of users. I have clients and developers and I want to differentiate between them to have different functionality for each profile. I do not know what could I do to manage this.

I am using Core Data for the objects of the app. So, should I do two entities? Or only one called User? Each user has relationships with other entities but they do not have relationships between them.

Like this:
`Developers(Desarrolladores), Clients(Clientes), Proyects(Proyectos), Offers(Ofertas)`...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is best to keep the core data model as simple as possible when you are starting out with your Core Data design.

Utilize one entity for a 'User' which holds an attribute for which type of User it is. Then add on functionality for these two different types of users with a category.  This way, if you change your mind about your design later, the functionality that you give to each will be preserved. Having done multiple adjustments to my data model, this is a must!

The rationale for this and an example of its implementation is provided by the [Stanford iOS development course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) on iTunesU in Lecture 13. Good luck and happy coding.